# Join List<string> Together with Commas Plus "and" for Last Element

Tags: c#, list

I know I could figure a way out but I am wondering if there is a more concise solution. There's always `String.Join(", ", lList)` and `lList.Aggregate((a, b) => a + ", " + b);` but I want to add an exception for the last one to have `", and "` as its joining string. Does `Aggregate()` have some index value somewhere I can use? Thanks.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You could do this

```
string finalString = String.Join(", ", myList.ToArray(), 0, myList.Count - 1) + ", and " + myList.LastOrDefault();
```

Comment: Don't know why I didn't think of something this simple. Thanks.

Comment: @keyboardP: I didn't downvote but would guess that the downvoter probably wants a little more info about how/why your solution works rather than a Give Teh Codez answer. If you expand a bit on your snippet, i.e. explain it, I'll upvote it!

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work if there is only one item in the list

Comment: If there are 0 items, then `finalString` will be `", and"`. If there is 1 item, then `finalString` will be `", and item1"`.

Comment: it throws an argument exception when myList is empty, because the count argument is -1, while it can't be less than 0.

Comment: see my answer below to get a working extension method. It will accept empty lists too

Comment: Indeed does not work. This should not be marked as answer.

Answer (score 26):

Here is a solution which works with empty lists and list with a single item in them:

#### C#

```
return list.Count() > 1 ? string.Join(", ", list.Take(list.Count() - 1)) + " and " + list.Last() : list.FirstOrDefault();
```

#### VB

```
Return If(list.Count() > 1, String.Join(", ", list.Take(list.Count() - 1)) + " and " + list.Last(), list.FirstOrDefault())
```

Comment: good. but if variable `list` is `IEnumerable`, it will be enumerated many many times - when calling `Count()`, `Take()`, `Count()` again, `Last()` and `FirstOrDefault()`. Very inefficient if it's not really an array or a `List<T>`

Answer (score 13):

I use the following extension method (with some code guarding too):

```
public static string OxbridgeAnd(this IEnumerable<String> collection)
{
    var output = String.Empty;

    var list = collection.ToList();

    if (list.Count > 1)
    {
        var delimited = String.Join(", ", list.Take(list.Count - 1));

        output = String.Concat(delimited, ", and ", list.LastOrDefault());
    }

    return output;
}
```

Here is a unit test for it:

```
 [TestClass]
    public class GrammarTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestThatResultContainsAnAnd()
        {
            var test = new List<String> { "Manchester", "Chester", "Bolton" };

            var oxbridgeAnd = test.OxbridgeAnd();

            Assert.IsTrue( oxbridgeAnd.Contains(", and"));
        }
    }
```

***EDIT***

This code now handles null and a single element:

```
  public static string OxbridgeAnd(this IEnumerable<string> collection)
    {
        var output = string.Empty;

        if (collection == null) return null;

        var list = collection.ToList();

        if (!list.Any()) return output;

        if (list.Count == 1) return list.First();

        var delimited = string.Join(", ", list.Take(list.Count - 1));

        output = string.Concat(delimited, ", and ", list.LastOrDefault());

        return output;
    }
```

Comment: This is a great starting point. I updated the body of the method to roughly look like this (compressed to fit here): `string output = string.Empty;
 List<string> input = value.ToList();

 if (input.Count > 2) { 
     string delimited = string.Join(", ", input.Take(input.Count - 1));
  output = string.Concat(delimited, ", and ", input.LastOrDefault());
 } else if (input.Count == 2) {
  output = string.Concat(input.FirstOrDefault(), " and ", input.LastOrDefault());
 } else { output = value.FirstOrDefault(); }

 return output;`

Comment: Good but has a little bug.  Fails if list contains only 1 item.

Comment: yes, it won't work if collection has only 1 item. Also this method is inefficient with long collections. It should use a StringBuilder to avoid copying really large strings multiple times, which makes it really slow

Comment: @ RitchieD @Artemious Fixed

Comment: You might want to add the following for only two strings: `if (list.Count == 2) return string.Join(" and ", list);`

Answer (score 8):

This version enumerates values once and works with any number of values:

```
public static string JoinAnd<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> values, string separator, string sepLast)
{
    if (values == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(values));

    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    var enumerator = values.GetEnumerator();

    if (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        sb.Append(enumerator.Current);
    }

    if (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        var obj = enumerator.Current;

        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            sb.Append(separator);
            sb.Append(obj);
            obj = enumerator.Current;
        }

        sb.Append(sepLast);
        sb.Append(obj);
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

*edit*: Fixed bug pointed out in @Artemious's answer to be like `string.Join`. Added xunit-test:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("")]
[InlineData("•")] // • mean null
[InlineData("a")]
[InlineData("ab")]
[InlineData("abc")]
[InlineData("•bc")]
[InlineData("a•c")]
[InlineData("ab•")]
[InlineData("•••")]
public void ResultsAreLikeStringJoinExceptForLastSeparator(string chars)
{
    const string separator = ", ";
    const string lastSeparator = " and ";

    var values = chars.Select(c => c == '•' ? null : c.ToString());

    var actualResult = values.JoinAnd(separator, lastSeparator);

    // Same result as string.Join, but with last ", " replaced with " and ".
    var stringJoined = string.Join(separator, values);
    var stringJoinLike = Regex.Replace(stringJoined, @", (?=\w?$)", lastSeparator);

    Assert.Equal(stringJoinLike, actualResult);
}
```

Comment: I do like this answer the best, however I would modify the method signature to be `public static string JoinAnd<T>(string separator, string sepLast, IEnumerable<T> values)`, for convenience of passing in, say, a `List<int>`

Comment: @BCA Yeah, thanks, that's better, I changed the answer.

Comment: I did a variation of this that also deals with the instance where you have 2 elements and just want them connected with " and ", by adding a 4th parameter, `divider` (defaulting to `" and "`), and adding an `index` counter to keep track of the current index of the element we're processing. In the last block, if `index == 1`, then I use `divider` instead of `sepLast`.

Comment: @Mason Hm? `JoinAnd(", ", " and ", twoItems)` should already cover it: The last (and only) separator become `sepLast` with value `" and "`.

Comment: @Grastveit Oxford commas. Otherwise you end up wondering if [Nelson Mandela is a dildo collector](https://www.reddit.com/r/BrandNewSentence/comments/aa7drp/nelson_mandela_an_800yearold_demigod_and_a_dildo/).

Answer (score 7):

This version enumerates values only once and works with any number of values.

*(Improved [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44886666/1830814) of @Grastveit)*

I converted it to an **extension method** and added some unit tests. Added some null-checks.
Also I fixed a bug when if an item in the `values` collection contains `null`, and it is the last one, it would be skipped at all. This does not correspond to how `String.Join()` behaves now in the .NET Framework.

```
#nullable enable
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Helpers;

public static class StringJoinExtensions
{
    public static string JoinAnd<T>(this IEnumerable<T?> values,
        in string separator = ", ",
        in string lastSeparator = ", and ") => JoinAnd(values, new StringBuilder(), separator, lastSeparator).ToString();

    public static StringBuilder JoinAnd<T>(this IEnumerable<T?> values,
        StringBuilder sb,
        in string separator = ", ",
        in string lastSeparator = ", and ")
    {
        _ = values ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(values));
        _ = separator ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(separator));
        _ = lastSeparator ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(lastSeparator));

        using var enumerator = values.GetEnumerator();

        // add first item without separator
        if (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            sb.Append(enumerator.Current);
        }

        var nextItem = (hasValue: false, item: default(T?));
        // see if there is a next item
        if (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            nextItem = (true, enumerator.Current);
        }

        // while there is a next item, add separator and current item
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            sb.Append(separator);
            sb.Append(nextItem.item);
            nextItem = (true, enumerator.Current);
        }

        // add last separator and last item
        if (nextItem.hasValue)
        {
            sb.Append(lastSeparator ?? separator);
            sb.Append(nextItem.item);
        }

        return sb;
    }
}
```

## Unit tests

```
#nullable enable
using Xunit;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Helpers;
using FluentAssertions;

namespace Helpers.Tests;

public class StringJoinExtensionsFixture
{
    [Theory]
    [InlineData("", "", null, null)]
    [InlineData("1", "1", null, null)]
    [InlineData("1 and 2", "1", "2", null)]
    [InlineData("1, 2 and 3", "1", "2", "3")]
    [InlineData(", 2 and 3", "", "2", "3")]
    public void ReturnsCorrectResults(string expectedResult,
         string string1, string string2, string string3)
    {
        var input = new[] { string1, string2, string3 }.Where(r => r != null);
        string actualResult = input.JoinAnd(", ", " and ");
        Assert.Equal(expectedResult, actualResult);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void ThrowsIfArgumentNulls()
    {
        Assert.Throws<ArgumentNullException>(() =>
             StringJoinExtensions.JoinAnd(default(string[])!, ", ", " and "));

        Assert.Throws<ArgumentNullException>(() =>
           StringJoinExtensions.JoinAnd(new[] { "1", "2" }, null!,
              " and "));

        Assert.Throws<ArgumentNullException>(() =>
           StringJoinExtensions.JoinAnd(new[] { "1", "2" }, "", null!));
    }

    [Fact]
    public void SeparatorsCanBeEmpty()
    {
        StringJoinExtensions.JoinAnd(new[] { "1", "2" }, "", ",")
            .Should().Be("1,2", "separator is empty");
        StringJoinExtensions.JoinAnd(new[] { "1", "2" }, ",", "")
            .Should().Be("12", "last separator is empty");
        StringJoinExtensions.JoinAnd(new[] { "1", "2" }, "", "")
            .Should().Be("12", "both separators are empty");
    }

    [Fact]
    public void ValuesCanBeNullOrEmpty()
    {
        StringJoinExtensions.JoinAnd(new[] { "", "2" }, "+", "-")
            .Should().Be("-2", "1st value is empty");
        StringJoinExtensions.JoinAnd(new[] { "1", "" }, "+", "-")
            .Should().Be("1-", "2nd value is empty");
        StringJoinExtensions.JoinAnd(new[] { "1", "2", "" }, "+", "-")
            .Should().Be("1+2-", "3rd value is empty");

        StringJoinExtensions.JoinAnd(new[] { null, "2" }, "+", "-")
            .Should().Be("-2", "1st value is null");
        StringJoinExtensions.JoinAnd(new[] { "1", null }, "+", "-")
            .Should().Be("1-", "2nd value is null");
        StringJoinExtensions.JoinAnd(new[] { "1", "2", null }, "+", "-")
            .Should().Be("1+2-", "3rd value is null");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can `values` ever be null though if this is an extension method being called on the IEnumerable itself?

Comment: it will throw an exception if called on a (null).JoinAnd(..)

Comment: Isn't the null exception happening before it even reaches your code, since there's no object available to call your extension method on, because it's null?

Comment: nope, extension methods work this way, they can be invoked on null

Answer (score -2):

The simplest way that I can think of is like this... print(', '.join(a[0:-1]) + ', and ' + a[-1])

```
a = [a, b, c, d]
print(', '.join(a[0:-1]) + ', and ' + a[-1])
```

> a, b, c, and d

Or, if you don't like Canadian syntax, the Oxford comma, and extra squiggles:

```
print(', '.join(a[0:-1]) + ' and ' + a[-1])
```

> a, b, c and d

Keeping it simple.

Comment: This looks like Python, this question is tagged with C#.