# c# linq csv change delimiter of last element

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

Considering the 3 examples:

1. function(["a"]) -> result = "a",
2. function(["a", "b"]) -> result = "a and b",
3. function(["a", "b", "c"]) -> result = "a, b and c"

Is there a more elegant or preferably efficient method than:

```
result = fieldList.Aggregate((a, b) => a.Replace(" and ", ", ") + " and " + b);
```

I am assuming fiedlList has at least one element.

Or traditional programming:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < fieldList.Count; i++)
{
    string field = fieldList[i];
    if (i == 0)
         sb.Append(field);
    else if (i == fieldList.Count - 1)
        sb.AppendFormat(" and {0}", field);
    else
        sb.AppendFormat(", {0}", field);
}
result = sb.ToString();
```

I cannot see a StringBuilder in the top option is going to work.

The only other way I think of is remove the last element first then append at the end:

```
var last = fieldList.Last();
fieldList.RemoveAt(fieldList.Count - 1);
result = fieldList.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, f) => { 
    if (sb.Length == 0) 
        sb.Append(f); 
    else
        sb.AppendFormat(", {0}", f);
    return sb;
}).ToString();
if (result.Length > 0)
    result += " and " + last;
else
    result = last;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17560201/join-liststring-together-with-commas-plus-and-for-last-element

Comment: @BikalBhattarai Technically speaking even that solution is incorrect if there is zero or one element as the result would still prepend the delimiter (" and " in my case) however; I did not think of that so perfect answer. So correct answer would be: string result = String.Join(", ", myList.ToArray(), 0, myList.Count - 1); if (myList.Length > 1)  result +=  " and " + myList.Last();

Answer (score 0):

Answer stolen from @BikalBhattarai suggestion and @Darren comment in that post:

```
result = String.Join(", ", fieldList.ToArray(), 0, fieldList.Count - 1); 
if (fieldList.Count > 1) 
    result += " and " + fieldList.Last();
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
var result = String.Join(" and ", new []
{
    String.Join(", ", fieldList.Take(fieldList.Length - 1)),
    fieldList.LastOrDefault()
}.Where(x => x != null));
```

It even works for an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Other solution

```
int count = fieldList.Count();
var result = string.Join(", ", fieldList.Take(count > 1 ? count - 1 : count))
    + (count > 1 ? " and " + fieldList.Last() : string.Empty);
```